# Getting an error when trying to get pandas to read my json file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm getting `ValueError: Expected object or value` when trying to get pandas to read my json file.

Here is the code I'm using:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
dataframe = pd.read_json(r'C:\Users\stans\WFH Project\data.json')
```

This is when I receive the value error. I saved the json data as a text file with the .json extension.

Here is a sample:

```json
{
    'created_at': 'Thu Dec 24 10:09:36 +0000 2020',
    'id': 1342049779233284097,
    'id_str': '1342049779233284097',
    'text': 'RT @ab: S2E13 IntelAI podcast—from #AI beating world chess champs to solving the grand research challenge known as the #protein…',
    'truncated': False,
    'entities': {
        'hashtags': [{
                'text': 'AI',
                'indices': [47, 50]
            }
```

I even tried saving the json file in pwd to see if it was a directory path issue, but I received the same error. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your JSON is valid? The sample is definitely not.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the JSON isn't valid. I went through JSONLint and it resulted in parse errors. I tried to format it correctly, but still getting errors. Afraid I don't have a lot of experience with properly formatting JSON. Any ideas on how to correct the JSON code?

Comment: I added an answer with what I would do to the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this updated JSON. I replaced all of the `'` with `"`, replaced `False` with `false`, and closed all of the arrays/objects...

```json
{
    "created_at": "Thu Dec 24 10:09:36 +0000 2020",
    "id": 1342049779233284097,
    "id_str": "1342049779233284097",
    "text": "RT @ab: S2E13 IntelAI podcast\u2014from #AI beating world chess champs to solving the grand research challenge known as the #protein\u2026",
    "truncated": false,
    "entities": {"hashtags": [{
        "text": "AI",
        "indices": [47, 50]
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use forward-slash ('/') for your path.
If doesn't work then try below.

````
import pandas as pd
with open('C:/Users/stans/WFH Project/data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)```
````

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm now getting 'ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index'

Comment: Got it, had to pass the index function to the df object. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import panda as pd 
   
f = open('C:/Users/stans/WFH Project/data.json',) 
data = json.load(f) 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
f.close()
```